# How to use java find a specific id in html code ( for automated form completion )?

Tags: java, eval

I'm interested in developing a ubiquitous forum completion script. I don't have much experience in java so I really could use some help.

Here's the problem, I have a html code like this

```
<input id="iLastName" name="iLastName" maxlength="40" placeholder="Last" onfocus...
```

This is a part of code of a form on a sign up website. Now the problem is, each field in the form has a specific id, the id is usually associated with the field, like for this one, the id for Last Name is "iLastName". There are usually a lot of other fields in the forum, i.e.  email, address etc., how can I search and extract the id based on whether it contains the content I'm looking for. Like for last name, I would simply check if the word "last" is inside the id.

Currently I managed to get the first field's id, by typing:

```
EVAL("\"{{!EXTRACT}}\".match(/<input[^>]*id=[\"\']([^\"^\']*)[\"\']*[>\\s]/i)[1];")
```

This gives me the id of the first field, but that's not enough...

Thanks so much! I really need some help with this!

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Comment: 1) It is not `JAVA` but `JavaSCRIPT`. 2) You should not parse HTML with regex (link above). 3) You should consider using `jQuery` as it will turn this task into something pretty simple.

Comment: Java is to JavaScript what a car is to a carpet.